# Checking string for correct input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im doing an activity to extend my existing code to check for user input and I can't get it to work properly.

- First attempt:

```py
while 5 > appcounter:
    StudentGender.append (input(StudentName[namecount]+",Please Enter Student Gender M or F:"))
    if StudentGender[appcounter] == "M":
        appcounter = appcounter + 1
        namecount = namecount + 1
    elif StudentGender[appcounter] == "F":
        appcounter = appcounter + 1
        namecount = namecount + 1
    else:
        print("Not a valid input")
```

- Second Try

```py
for Counter in range (ConstNoStudents+1):
    try:
        StudentGender[Counter] = (input(StudentName[namecount]+",are you Male or Female, Please use M or F:") )
        StudentGender[Counter] = "M" or "F" or "f" or "m"
        namecount = listcount+1
    except:
        print("That is not a valid number")
```

I ideally want it to identify when the user type's something other than M or F in and Get the user to re-enter the value without adding anything extra to the list

Comment: Welcome to [so]!

Comment: You'd better validate the input before appending it to `StudentGender`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging your code, you need to prompt the user again if his input is invalid. You can do so with a while loop :

```
for index in range(ConstNoStudents+1):
    input = input(StudentName[index]+", are you Male or Female, Please use M or F:")
    while not input.upper() in ["M", "F"]:
        input = input("Invalid input. Please use M or F :")
    StudentGender[index] = input
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to get the input in a loop and check if one of the correct values was entered and if it was not, then repeat the loop.

You can also apply `.upper()` to the gender selection, instead of specifying the lower case versions of the gender values.

```
invalid_gender = True
while invalid_gender:
    gender = input('Please Enter Student Gender (M or F):')

    if gender.upper() not in ['M', 'F']:
        print('Invalid gender! Please, try again.')
    else:
        invalid_gender = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```py
accepted_inputs = ["M", "F"]
while True:
    user_input = input("message")
    if user_input in accepted_inputs:
        break
    print("Bad input, try again")
```